# Wrong queue of events in TRIGGER

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have got table person which have got 2 triggers (if data is inserted, triggers make update) all triggers are **after insert** later I insert information about events to other table and I get (Update, Update, Insert) but should be this (Insert, Update, Update) do you know why?

I have got problem with this example:

```
    DECLARE @HistoryType CHAR(1) --"I"=insert, "U"=update, "D"=delete
    SET @HistoryType=NULL

    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   inserted)
      BEGIN
          IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   deleted)
            BEGIN
                --UPDATE
                SET @HistoryType='U'
            END
          ELSE
            BEGIN
                --INSERT
                SET @HistoryType='I'
            END
      END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   deleted)
      BEGIN
          --DELETE
          SET @HistoryType='D'
      END
    IF @HistoryType='U' or @HistoryType='I'
   //do something
    END
```

Example from this post:

[How to copy an inserted,updated,deleted row in a SQL Server trigger(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391393/how-to-copy-an-inserted-updated-deleted-row-in-a-sql-server-triggers)

Comment: So, you have two AFTER INSERT triggers?

Comment: @gbn Do you know where can be problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guaranteed order to trigger firing, unless you use [sp_settriggerorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx). 
But then you'll have to set this every time you run ALTER TRIGGER.

Personally, I would never have 2 triggers on the same action, so I would do one of these

- Use a single trigger to make things simpler
- Use a stored procedure so the logic is more transparent

This includes things having both before and after triggers: this begs for a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for helped. I also think it`s wrong way to have more then one trigger in table but it`s not my decision.